# Why memory is not allocated?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was required to built a function that allocates memory to a pointer to form an array but whatever I try it doesen't allocate memory .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void alocare(int **a,int n)
{
   *a = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
     int *a ,*b,*c,n,m,k;
    printf("Insert the number of elements for the first array:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Insert the number of elements for the second array:\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    
    printf("Number of bytes ocupied by a before alloc(): %d\n",sizeof(a));
    printf("Number of bytes occupied by b before alloc(): %d\n",sizeof(b));
    alocare(&a,n);
    alocare(&b,m);
    printf("Number of bytes ocupied by a after alloc(): %d\n",sizeof(a));
    printf("Number of bytes ocupied by b after alloc(): %d\n",sizeof(a));
    return 0;
}
```

The size that it's displayed in the two printf in the main is 4 before allocation and after it and I can't understand why
Thanks!

Comment: What is ... `sizeof (a_pointer)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(a)` returns the size of the type of `a`. Since `a` is a pointer, its size is always `4` (in your platform; in others it might be `8` or something else). This size will never change: it is a constant for your program.

There is no way to know what is the size of allocated memory behind a pointer unless you save it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

memory is allocated.

However, if you just use sizeof(a), it will return the 'size of pointer' not a 'size of whole array memory'

you can use '_msize' in Windows to find size of memory inside of your pointer.

```
_msize // in windows
malloc_size // in MacOS
```

[image]

it works on Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: These functions are non standard and they shouldn't be used ever.

Comment: Also theere is no reason to include plain text output as an image in your answer. It is much easier to copy/paste the text as text.

Comment: @Jabberwocky except maybe when debugging